# Is it possible to use ganache blockchain when I deploy my web app in heroku? or should I deploy the contract first to a test network?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, nodejs, ganache, kovan

```
const web3 = new Web3(
  new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
    "https://kovan.infura.io/v3/INFURA_KEY"
  )
);
const abi = JSON.parse(
  '[ { "constant": false, "inputs": [ { "internalType": "string", "name": "_patientId", "type": "string" }, { "internalType": "string", "name": "_medicalHistoryId", "type": "string" }, { "internalType": "string", "name": "_medicalHistory", "type": "string" } ], "name": "insertMedicalHistory", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [ { "internalType": "string", "name": "_patientId", "type": "string" }, { "internalType": "string", "name": "_recordId", "type": "string" }, { "internalType": "string", "name": "_record", "type": "string" } ], "name": "insertRecord", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [ { "internalType": "string", "name": "_patientId", "type": "string" }, { "internalType": "string", "name": "_medicalHistoryId", "type": "string" } ], "name": "getMedicalHistory", "outputs": [ { "internalType": "string", "name": "", "type": "string" } ], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [ { "internalType": "string", "name": "_patientId", "type": "string" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "_dataIndex", "type": "uint256" } ], "name": "getMedicalHistoryId", "outputs": [ { "internalType": "string", "name": "", "type": "string" } ], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [ { "internalType": "string", "name": "_patientId", "type": "string" }, { "internalType": "string", "name": "_recordId", "type": "string" } ], "name": "getRecord", "outputs": [ { "internalType": "string", "name": "", "type": "string" } ], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [ { "internalType": "string", "name": "_patientId", "type": "string" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "_dataIndex", "type": "uint256" } ], "name": "getRecordId", "outputs": [ { "internalType": "string", "name": "", "type": "string" } ], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [ { "internalType": "string", "name": "_patientId", "type": "string" } ], "name": "totalMedHis", "outputs": [ { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256" } ], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [ { "internalType": "string", "name": "_patientId", "type": "string" } ], "name": "totalRecord", "outputs": [ { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256" } ], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" } ]'
);
const contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(
  abi,
  "0x6De8Ec028eb57417Db911AdcE4b6D96a5A2bBF57"
);

//SAMPLE INSTANCE IN MY REST API

     contractInstance.methods
        .insertMedicalHistory(req.params.id, medHisId, ciphertext.toString())
        .send({
          from: "0xE9Ca8E74b607234AbF2040b5711b4F218cA84b40",
          gas: 6721975
        });
```

I deployed my contract in kovan, is this correct? are there any mistakes? then I will use that instance to send something in the blockchain. However, when I tried it. It was not inserted in the blockchain.

Comment: Please remove your Infura API key from the question.

Comment: is that correct?

Comment: Yes, now, when are you invoking the insertMedicalHistory() method do you get any error?

Comment: In localhost, is it working perfectly fine but when I deployed my app in heroku, the medical history was not inserted.

Comment: I have checked the transaction details for the above stated contract address, till now you have performed 3 transactions to this contract, wherein the data part on etherscan I see a huge hex string, I just want to know the types of parameters passed to inserMedicalHistory() such that we can confirm is that method being actually invoked or not?

Comment: function insertMedicalHistory(
        string memory _patientId,
        string memory _medicalHistoryId,
        string memory _medicalHistory
    )

these are the parameters of insertMedicalHistory()

Comment: By looking at the data on Etherscan, your contract's insertRecord() function is called and not insertMedicalHistory(). The signature on etherscan  for the method is `0xc8d24bae` which is for insertRecord() and not insertMedicalHistory()

Comment: function insertRecord(
        string memory _patientId,
        string memory _recordId,
        string memory _record
    )

yes but it's just the same parameters. I know that the contract works because that 3 transaction was from the remix ide.

Comment: can I just use ganache even if I deployed my app in heroku?

Comment: Instead of directly invoking insertMedicalHistory(), try sending a rawTransaction() instead, and yes you can use ganache

Comment: I'll try that one. If that's the case I think the problem is with heroku because again when I use the localhost for the development of my app. It's working totally fine.

Comment: It's not a problem with Heroku.

Comment: There still no block added when I use my app.